# Log in problem in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: login

Following screen appears in my ubuntu 18.04 blinking(ubuntu logo and some texts scrolling) as the system boots up. The processing screen does not allow my log in screen to appear. I have to power off the system forcefully and reboot to get my log in screen. One of my key (page up) is faulty. Other than that I do not have any other problem in my sytem. Can I have a solution to this? Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: You need to provide more details than that. Because the amount of details you provided is incompleted and hard to comprehend. Which version of Ubuntu you're using?
What are your findings?
When you get to the system and get logged in did you try to look into the logs of `journalctl` ?
And lastly the picture isn't much of help since it's too blurry to read anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would suggest is to use boot-repair through a USB (hopefully you have another computer to create the USB). The steps are here below:

1) Download the Boot Repair ISO from Sourceforge. Link: https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/

2) Open disks, then click the selection on the top-right corner, then click 'Recover Disk Image', then select the Boot Repair ISO (for Ubuntu). If you're on Windows, try using Pendrive Linux to burn the ISO.

3) Reboot into BIOS, then select boot into your USB. Don't change any settings on the Boot Repair.

4) Run the automatic repair tool. Most of the time it will either fix the problem or tell you specifically what it is and what you need to do next.

Good luck!

Comment: I will try this and let you know.